# Use "whom" or "who"

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns, who-whom

1. Anyone **whom** completed a Discrete mathematics course ?
2. Anyone **who** completed a Discrete mathematics course ?

Which one sentence is grammatically more accurate I feel resistance to use any one of it.

Comment: Neither one is a complete or correct sentence, so it's hard to say which one is more accurate, although #2 comes closer.  Can you say what you want in different words?  I suspect what you mean is "Has anyone completed a Discrete mathematics course?" or "Is there anyone who has completed a Discrete mathematics course?"

Comment: @stangdon yes i was looking same sentence "Has anyone completed a Discrete mathematics course?" or "Is there anyone who has completed a Discrete mathematics course?"  Both sentence are give me a hint where i am wrong . But in my case first one match my situation. Thanks a lot to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

"Who" is the subject in the sentence, "whom" is the object. Your sentence doesn't have a good form using "whom", so I'll give another example where both words can be used.

You can ask:
 - Who spoke to you?
 - With whom did you speak?

A good way to remember is to think about how the question would be answered.
 - *He* spoke to me -> who
 - I spoke to *him* -> whom